# Wrong encoding on PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest POST

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm using Invoke-WebRequest POST method to send an text data. After sending the text in a wrong encoding.

Script:

```
$postData = "žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://www.mydomain.com/' -Method Post -Body $postData -ContentType "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
```

Fiddler:

```
POST http://www.mydomain.com/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 6.2; cs-CZ) WindowsPowerShell/4.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Host: www.mydomain.com
Content-Length: 31

zlutouck� kun �pel d�belsk� �dy
```

**Edited**:

It seems that it is necessary to first convert the text into utf8. PowerShell ISE uses a different encoding by default.
In my case, windows-1250.

```
$text = "žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy"
$postData = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($text)
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://www.mydomain.com/' -Method Post -Body $postData -ContentType "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
```

Comment: Please post your edit as an answer to your question; [that's how we do things around here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes()` didn't work for me. Output is like `[29, 118, 61, 80, 267...]`

Comment: PowerShell version is important for this topic. I can do UTF8 string as post body without any problems on PS 5.1 but for PS 4.0 I need to save string to the file and then use web request with -InFile parameter instead of -Body

Answer (score 24):

This worked for me:

```
$postData = "žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://www.example.com/' -Method Post -Body $postData 
 -ContentType "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
```

Adding the **charset=utf-8** fixed my issue where the acute accent characters were getting converted to special symbols.

Comment: note: content type can be "application/json" etc. not restricted to "text/plain"

Answer (score 8):

I had to do two things to solve the problem. Encode the body and add the charset to the header:

```
$body = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($body);

$headers = @{
            "Content-Type"="application/json; charset=utf-8";
            "OData-MaxVersion"="4.0";
            "OData-Version"="4.0";
        };

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$($odataEndpoint)systemusers($userid)" -Method PATCH -Headers $headers -Body $body -UseDefaultCredentials
```

Comment: I get back `Headers: {[Connection, keep-alive], [Keep-Alive, timeout=5], [Content-Length, 7], [Content-Type, text/html; charset=utf-8],`, my request is `... -Headers @{'Content-Type'='application/json'}`. I think that `-headers` or -contenttype` does not matter.