# French accents in Microsoft graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, diacritics

I'm working on a project on Microsoft Graph with PowerShell, where i have to create a planner.

So, i'm using POST requests to create buckets, tasks, ... But some of them have accents in their name, description, ... (à faire, terminée, ...). And when i'm running the script, the result shown in the planner is unreadable : "Termin�e"

I've already tried to change the encoding to UTF-8, or modify these names with url encode, but none of them worked.

Is there a way to correctly display these accents with Microsoft Graph ?

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducable example with some sample code?

Comment: What do you mean by "reproducable example" ? the planner ? the azure active directory app ? all the code that leads to the creation of the bucket / tasks ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you.

Comment: Ok, i'll work on it. Is there a way to update my question, or should i write another one ?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure it out either. Looks like Graph doesn't support accents/diacritics properly yet, so I resorted to creating the objects via Graph then (re)setting DisplayName using [PNP commandlets](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP).

It'll probably figure itself out in time.

Comment: I take that back - it turns out ISE uses the wrong sort of encoding and [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598398/wrong-encoding-on-powershell-invoke-webrequest-post/51481644) figured it out.

Encode your POST data first:
`$postData = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($text)`
 Then add `; charset=utf-8"` to the ContentType of the Web Request

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll try it soon. And I will tell you if it worked.