# How to send UTF8 to the WordPress REST-API?

Tags: json, wordpress, rest, powershell

> Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Disclaimer: Character encodings confuse me a lot.
I want to create a lot of posts automated via the WordPress REST-API. I can create posts without an issue - unless I got *special* characters in my content. Emojis for example.

```
$params = @{
    title = $Title
    content = $Content # "foobar" would work just fine; 
                       # "äöü" will give me an error
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://my.blog.foo/wp-json/v2/posts" `
                  -Method POST `
                  -Headers @{ Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $ACCESS_TOKEN) } ` 
                  -ContentType "application/json" `
                  -UseBasicParsing `
                  -Body $($params | ConvertTo-Json)
```

I assume this actually isn't a WordPress related issue. Anyhow I'm fiddling aroundd for quite a while now and I just can't figure out a way to send my content without malforming ("ö" gets "?") it.

Comment: Use `-ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8"` instead. If this is still not working, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/21598398/934946 for additional actions you can take (such as encoding body / adding contenttype header)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8";`  instead.

If it doesn't work, You might also need to encode your body to UTF8 too.
`$body = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($body);`

**Complete example**

```
$params = @{
    title = $Title
    content = $Content # "foobar" would work just fine; 
                       # "äöü" will give me an error
}

$Body = $params | ConvertTo-Json
$Body = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($body)

$Splat_Post= @{
    ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    UseBasicParsing = $true
    Method = 'POST'
    Uri = "https://my.blog.foo/wp-json/v2/posts"
    Headers = @{ Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $ACCESS_TOKEN) }
}

Invoke-RestMethod @Splat_Post-Body $Body
```

Note: I reworked the code to demonstrate [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) .

Should you need to call that method with all the same parameters each time except body, you could call it like that : 
`Invoke-RestMethod @Splat_Post -Body $Body`  then just changing the $Body to the content of your desires each time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and encode the body as UTF8 before posting it

```
-Body ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(($params | ConvertTo-Json)))
```