# Powershell Invoke-Webrequest encodes filename of uploaded file to Base64 when it contains german umlaut

Tags: powershell, file-upload, base64, invoke-webrequest

when I'm uploading a file using Powershell Invoke-Webrequest, then the filename gets encoded to base64 when it contains a german umlaut, otherwise it stays in the original encoding. Here's an example:

```
$path = "C:\test\Peter Müller.txt"
$uploadFormDict = @{}
$uploadFormDict['myfile'] = Get-Item -Path $path
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.my-example-url.de/upload" -Method POST -Form $uploadFormDict
```

The filename that has been uploaded is '=?utf-8?B?UGV0ZXIgTcO8bGxlci50eHQ=?=', so the Base64-encoded string 'UGV0ZXIgTcO8bGxlci50eHQ=?=' of 'Peter Müller.txt' with a prepended '=?utf-8?B?'.
If I upload a file named 'Peter Mueller.txt', the filename stays 'Peter Mueller.txt'.
How can handle that the filename will not be encoded to Base64?

Thank you!

Comment: `Get-Item -Path $path` returns a FileInfo **object**, not just a file name. Did you mean to get the content of the file perhaps?

Comment: I know that Get-Item returns a FileInfo object. This FileInfo object is stored in the dictionary that is passed to the -Form argument of the Invoke-WebRequest (see the Powershell Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.2#example-6-simplified-multipart-form-data-submission). And the issue I'm referring is that in the request the filename is then Base64-encoded.

Comment: Did you save your script in UTF-8 ?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598398/wrong-encoding-on-powershell-invoke-webrequest-post) may be the same issue, but I'm not entirely convinced that it is.

Comment: I found a solution. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. For that I had to debug Powershell to see that [they use the ContentDispositionHeaderValue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/e7f90f0aa7e8dbdbe199c6120c2d5239a32c7427/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/WebCmdlet/Common/WebRequestPSCmdlet.Common.cs#L1934) and that the Name property of the FileInfo still contains the original name, but the FileName property of the ContentDispositionHeaderValue contains the encoded string ([seen here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/e7f90f0aa7e8dbdbe199c6120c2d5239a32c7427/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/WebCmdlet/Common/WebRequestPSCmdlet.Common.cs#L1971)).

[In the documentation of ContentDispositionHeaderValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.contentdispositionheadervalue.filename?view=net-6.0#remarks) I found that "The FileName property uses MIME encoding for non-ascii characters." [Here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipurpose_Internet_Mail_Extensions#MIME_Part_3_%E2%80%93_Header_Extensions_for_Non-ASCII_Text) is a description of MIME encoding, which matches exactly the format of encoded string I have encountered.

The solution was in my case to [decode that filename back at the server side](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.iconv-mime-decode.php).